# Data sharing to already loded components angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

I am having 3 section in page. 1 is left-component, 2 is right-component And 3 is Header-component.
What i want to do is once i change the route from left-component , i want to update some data in header-component, But header-component is already loded, so, how can i access the data within already loded component,
**Except - ngDocheck()**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the router events

```
ths.router.events.subscribe();
```

Or a service with a proxy (That you will trigger on route change)

```
export class MyService {
  dataToShare = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
}
...
this.myService.dataToShare.subscribe();
```

Or a lot of other ways. Best would be to give a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com) so that we can see the context and adapt the answer.

Comment: Actually passing data is not problem. how to catch that data ... when component is already loded... like you can do with ngDocheck() for change detection.. but that is not best approach

Comment: I have explained to you how. Either router events or proxies.